# How to display the table below correctly

Tags: php, html

I have a table which is currently displayed like this:

```
Question        OptionType
What is 2+2
What is 3+3
What is 4+4
A-D
A-C
A-E
```

But I do not want it displayed like this obviously, the questions should go under the "Questions" heading and the option types should go under the "OptionType" heading. How can I get the table to be displayed as below:

```
Question        OptionType
What is 2+2     A-D
What is 3+3     A-C
What is 4+4     A-E
```

Below is the code:

```
echo "<table>
  <tr>
  <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
  <th class='optiontypeth'>Option Type</th>
  </tr>";
  foreach ($searchResults as $question) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td></tr>';
          }
  foreach ($searchOption as $option) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($option).'</td></tr>';
}
  echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build the arrays, merge them together so that it will look like

```
$results[] = array('question' => $question, 'type'=> $type)
```

then you would do

```
foreach($results as result) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($result['question']).'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($result['type']).'</td></tr>';
    }
```

However using the code you gave me, I would do it like this

```
echo "<table>
  <tr>
  <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
  <th class='optiontypeth'>Option Type</th>
  </tr>";
  foreach ($searchResults as $key=>$question) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($searchOption[$key]).'</td></tr>';
  }

  echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

A table us not the correct tag to use for this type of application. Instead you should be using a definition list, which is more semantically applicable.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Question</dt><dd>OptionType</dd>
    <dt>What is 2+2</dt><dd>A-D</dd>
    ....
</dl>
```

See: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/

Answer (score 0):

you can not set to foreach printing those variables separate, I think that this will do, I just hope that each variable has the same length and has numeric keys

```
for($i=0;$i<count($searchOption);$i++){
    echo '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($searchResults[$i]).'</td><td>'.htmlspecialchars($searchOption[$i]).'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: if one is not concerned with micro optimization then this shouldn't pose a problem but otherwise this will raise a red flag, try putting the result of `count()` on a separate variable instead of accessing it everytime the index change, ie. `$count = count($searchOption); .. foreach($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)`..